# How to add an Image Reference to for Side/Front/Top

Tags: image

I'm new to Blender's menu and all and I see a-lot of users use an image reference to make their 3D model.
How do you add image to the side/front/top ?

Comment: Hi. Please remember to search the site before asking a question.

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>N</kbd> to bring the properties panel, then enable Background images and select the image.

By default using an image as background will enable the image for all of the preset views.

By selecting the Axis you can restrict the image to appear in only one view.

[image]

To have more than one image simply add more images and specify an axis for them:

[image]

Remember that Background images will only be displayed in:

1. **Camera Perspective** view (<kbd>Numpad 0</kbd>)
2. Any of the *preset* orthographic views which you can access using the keys on the number pad:

   - Front/Back (<kbd>Numpad 1</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Numpad 1</kbd>)
   - Right /Left (<kbd>Numpad 3</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Numpad 3</kbd>)
   - Top/Bottom (<kbd>Numpad 7</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Numpad 7</kbd>)

Background images will not show in perspective view. To switch between perspective and [orthographic][3] view use <kbd>Numpad 5</kbd>

Background images are used for reference only and will not be part of the final render.